# controller always loads index, never the method in the url

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I'm trying to create a 'double opt-in' subscribe sequence. I have the single form taking the individuals email, adding it the the database and then email with a confirmation link (`[base url]/controller/confirmEmail/[email hash]`). Once the user clicks the link  its supposed to take them to the same page as the form, but instead of the form, it should load a small success page.

All of this is done via one controller and one model. Im not sure if I should split the work into 2 controllers or not. But here is the code for the specific method that gets called in the link:

```
public function confirmEmail($hash) {
    $this->load->model('email_model');
    $email = $this->email_model->confirm_email($hash);
    if($email){
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['include'] = "confirmSuccess.php";
    } else {
        $data['include'] = "confirmFailure.php";
    }
    $this->load->view('working_view', $data); 
}
```

`$this->email_model->confirm_email($hash)` calls the model to try and update the status on the email in the database and returns the email if successful, false otherwise.

The `$data['include']` is for the small section that changes for various status changes (like adding to database, displaying the form, successful confirmation). in the `index` function, is when the form is displayed but setting the `$data['include']` there. But when the link is clicked in the email, the form is displayed instead of the 2 php pages set in the method above.

This has had me scratching my head for a good bit now. Not sure why the index is being loaded if the method loads the view on its own. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out.

What happened was that my routing was messing up, i had it set to accept parameters but of the wrong type (text only but the has is alphanumeric, so i had to adjust it to `/(:any)`, that i guess allowed for my parameter to be passed and it works